# Javascript - which type of logic is used for this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay i am unaware of what to search for to get information about how to solve this.

Basically everyday there will be 3 random images, but they must not exceed a total of xvw (etc 100vw)

Insted of giving each image a max width of lets say calc(3/100) i would like to have a more dynamic live width for the images.

Example [here](http://xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/VIGTIG/Javascript/imagesizeVW/index.php)  (Scroll down to see sample 02)

As you see in sample 01 it is really awesome the large image can take alot of width while the images which is not as wide do not use up all the view width which looks really great.

As you see in sample 02 it kinda breaks when there are two wide images which gives a bad effect to the whole user experince.

So if the 3 images exceeds 100vw i kinda need to set their max width accordingly somehow? but how do i check for this?

CSS

```
    .wrapper{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    .wrapper img{
        max-width: 50vw;
        max-height: 50vh;
    }
```

HTML

```
<h2>Sample 01</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="img4.jpg" alt="#">
    <img src="img2.jpg" alt="#">
    <img src="img3.jpg" alt="#">
</div>
<h2>Sample 02</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="img4.jpg" alt="#">
    <img src="img5.jpg" alt="#">
    <img src="img3.jpg" alt="#">
</div>
```

Javascript?

So basically what do i need to search for to get information about this type of problem?

This is not a jQuery question ^^

Comment: You could add the property: `flex: 1` to the images in css

Comment: This only take up the remaning height which is not what i am looking for.... i need the 3 images to be in 1 line no matter how wide they are, so they do not flex-wrap: wrap ish :) so their max width has to adjust accordingly but still make the widest image take up as much of the space as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use a flexbox to get all your pictures take the same height, and a width according to their aspect ratio.

Now, use a small function to recalculate the height of the container so that the new width fits the available space (in this case the window)

For simplicity, i run the function on onclick, you could call it on load, or similar.

```js
function resize () {
    var ctn = document.getElementById("container");
    var width = ctn.offsetWidth;
    var height = ctn.offsetHeight;
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth - 50;
    var ratio = windowWidth / width;
    ctn.style.height = height * ratio + 'px';
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" onclick="resize()">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="item" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" class="item" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" class="item" />
</div>
```